# How to call a class or what pattern to use?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I have `MailManager` it has public method like what:

```
public MailMessage ConfirmationEmail(CommonTicketEmailViewModel viewModel)
        {
            var template = ReadTemplate("ConfirmationEmail.cshtml");
            string result = Razor.Parse(template, new { ConfirmationUrl = viewModel.Url, Token = viewModel.Code });

            var mailMessage = new MailMessage();
            mailMessage.Subject = "Confirmation E-mail";
            mailMessage.Body = result;
            mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
            mailMessage.To.Add(viewModel.ToEmail);

            return mailMessage;
        }
```

this class just prepare MailMessage to send. Will how correct call this class?

Comment: I am confused, what is your question here? Are you asking for patterns of invoking the class methods?

Comment: My class just prepare mailMessage. All method prepare mailMessage. I do not like that I called it MailManager

Comment: Opinion based... But you can try some flavor of `____Factory` as a name (since it seem to be a factory for some sort of messages).

Comment: `Postman`?  Seems pertinent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about `MailMessageUtilities` or `MailMessageFactory`?

Comment: Please not `____Utilities`...

Comment: Utilities is bad. Factory better...